# load child component without parent component

Tags: angular

I want to ask if it's possible to load child component via URL or something else and display all information related to child component without accessing parent component, as I need to access to child from an external application and I want to skip the parent component page, so I need a way to access directly to child component I try to use directly the URL related to child component but it redirects me to parent page, as you can see this is the route for the application :

```
    const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '',redirectTo: 'home-component',pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'home-component', component: HomeComponent },

  { path: 'steps-component', component: StepsComponent,
    children:[
      { path: 'welcome-component', component:WelcomeComponent, outlet:'step' },
      { path: 'step1-component', component: Step1Component, outlet:'step' },
      { path: 'step2-component', component: Step2Component, outlet:'step' },
 ]
  },
];
```

Could you please help me with a solution to access directly to a child component I'm using angular 9?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is against to modularity and component based programming.
So, you can not acces them directly unless you define them in new route.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '',redirectTo: 'home-component',pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home-component', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'steps-component', component: StepsComponent,
    children:[
      { path: 'welcome-component', component:WelcomeComponent, outlet:'step' },
      { path: 'step1-component', component: Step1Component, outlet:'step' },
      { path: 'step2-component', component: Step2Component, outlet:'step' },
    ]
  },
  { path: 'welcome-component', component: WelcomeComponent },
  { path: 'step1-component', component: Step1Component },
  { path: 'step2-component', component: Step2Component },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking out for the same thing.

So far the only way I could figure out to do so is to use a hack, i.e. `*ngIf`.

Based on certain condition we can skip HTML of parent, and only show the children.